# JCarousel animate on mouse over

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jcarousel

Can the JQuery plugin "JCaousel" be configured to animate when the mouse is hovered over the next or prev buttons?

I have tried using the event "hover" but this didn't animate at all.

I have tried using the events "mouseover" and "mouseenter" but both of these only animate one time when the mouse is positioned over the button.  The user then has to move the mouse off of the button and then move it back in order to get another animation.  What I desire is a smooth continuous animation as long as the mouse is hovered.

Here is the code I've tried so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#AllTellers').jcarousel({ buttonNextEvent: 'mouseover', buttonPrevEvent: 'mouseover' });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer to your question in [THIS OTHER QUESTION - /how-do-i-fire-a-click-continuously-while-something-is-hovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429790/how-do-i-fire-a-click-continuously-while-something-is-hovered)

This answer talks about jCarouselLite but it sould be the same in jCarousel