# How do i fire a click continuously while something is hovered?

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseover, jcarousel

Im pretty sure this has a simple solution.  I am using jCarousellite, and i want to change the behaviour of built in nav buttons to fire on hover over.

```
$("#carousel").jCarouselLite({


 vertical: true,
 btnNext: ".btn-down",
 btnPrev: ".btn-up",
 visible:6,
 circular: false

});

$("#carousel .btn-down").hover(function() {

 $("#carousel .btn-down").click();

});
```

but it only fires once when mouseover, i need it to fire continueously while mouseover.

Comment: Stating your desired effect might be a better start, continuously firing a click has never been the best solution every time this has been asked.

Comment: Ah, sry!  I want the carousel to move to the next item while hovered.  Figured using the built in functionality of jCarouselLite would be the quickest solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var nav = function() {
  $("#carousel .btn-down").click(); // next move
  $("#carousel").data(
    'hover', 
    window.setTimeout(nav, 1000); // continue in 1000 ms
  );
};
$("#carousel .btn-down").hover(
  nav,
  function() {
    window.cancelTimeout ($("#carousel").data('hover')); // stop the navigation
  }
);
```

Comment: this Worked perfectly.  It surprising to me that the solutions needs to be so roundt about.  Cheers mate!

Answer (score 4):

I too had the same problem with my code, then I came up with this solution..

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("someid1").hover(function a() {  //on hover over some element with id-> someid1  
        $("#someid2").animate({
            width:"+=10" 
        }, function(){
            a();
        });
    }); //execute animation function and call itself again and again on mouseover
});                                                     

$("someid1").mouseout(function() {
    $("#someid2").stop(); //stop the animation on mouseout.
});
});
```

That did the trick for me. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `setInterval` to begin triggering the event at regular intervals on hover and use `clearInterval` to stop it when the user stops hovering. It'd also be cleaner to trigger the actual behavior you want instead of triggering a click event, assuming the plugin you're using supports such an API. Something like this:

```
var effectInterval;

$('#carousel .btn-down').hover(function() {
  effectInterval = setInterval(function() {
    $('#carousel').advanceToNextImage(); // sample API call, check your plugin's docs for how it might actually be done
  }, 5000);
}, function() {
  clearInterval(effectInterval);
});
```

Comment: *please* don't use strings in setInterval or setTimeout, it's bad practice and adds extra processing for no reason...it's even longer in this case: `setInterval(triggerEffect, 5000);`

Comment: @Nick - Ha, I just edited my answer to change that, then saw your comment as soon as the edit saved.

Comment: What is `advanceToNextImage`?  I think you're looking at another gallery plugin?

Comment: @Nick - it's a made up API call. It's just to show an example of calling the behavior as opposed to triggering a click event. I'll edit my answer again to make this clear... apparently edit messages don't show up on the actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an interval for clicking like this, just do the same for the opposite button:

```
$("#carousel .btn-down").hover(function() {
  $(this).data("to", setInterval(function() { $("#carousel .btn-down").click(); }, 200));
}, function() {
  clearInterval($(this).data("to"));
});
```