# Continuously scroll jCarousel on button hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

I'm using the jCarousel plugin and I've hit a road bump...

I need the carousel to continuously scroll whenever the navigation buttons are hovered.  Changing the built-in configuration variables to "mouseover" just scrolls once per hover.

I came across [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429790/how-do-i-fire-a-click-continuously-while-something-is-hovered) but I'm not a javascript expert and can't get the answer to work.

Here's my code:

```
    function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel)
{

    // Pause autoscrolling if the user moves with the cursor over the clip.
    carousel.clip.hover(function() {
        carousel.stopAuto();
    }, function() {
        carousel.startAuto();
    });
};

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        auto: 10,
        start: 1,
        scroll: 1,
        animation: 'slow',
        wrap: 'circular',
        buttonNextEvent: 'mouseover',
        buttonPrevEvent: 'mouseover',
        initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback
    });
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following script to make it work. I have tested it on `jquery.jcarousel.js` and `jquery-1.4.1`

To note, my jcarousel settings did not have auto scroll.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var _this = null;
    $('.jcarousel-next').mouseover(function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("jcarousel-next-disabled")) {
            _this = $(this);
            _this.click();
            window.setTimeout(CallAgain, 100);
        }
    });

    $('.jcarousel-next').mouseout(function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("jcarousel-next-disabled")) {
            _this = null;
        }
    });

    function CallAgain() {
        if (_this != null) {
            //alert("Inside Call again");
            _this.click();
            window.setTimeout(CallAgain, 100);
        }
    };

    $('.jcarousel-prev').mouseover(function() {
        if (!jQuery(this).hasClass("jcarousel-prev-disabled")){
            _this = $(this);
            _this.click();
            window.setTimeout(CallAgain, 100);
        }
    });

    $('.jcarousel-prev').mouseout(function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("jcarousel-next-disabled")) {
            _this = null;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Where would you put this script, in the .html file where the carousel is being displayed? Additionally, does this require the 'buttonNextEvent' and 'buttonPrevEvent' to be set to 'click' instead of 'mouseover'?